# Origin of Aliens in 'A Quiet Place'?

Tags: plot-explanation, a-quiet-place

There is no explanation given as to where the aliens originated from. Are they a result of meteor strike that I could see it on a piece of newspaper on his board?

Comment: Could you edit this to not be spoilers in the HNQ?

Comment: @zero298 Is this really a spoiler? Granted, I've never watched the film, but I don't see how the fact that the creatures are aliens really spoils anything.

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/185074/how-did-the-aliens-get-to-earth-in-a-quiet-place

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Yes.

Their planet was exploded and resulted in a meteor strike. So, the question arises "how did they survive this explosion". Well, it is because they have a shield making them almost invulnerable.

From [this excerpt of the podcast with John Krasinski](https://collider.com/a-quiet-place-monsters-explained/) (emphasis mine),

> **They are absolutely aliens. They’re from another planet.**
>
> **The idea behind all that is they’re definitely aliens and they’re an evolutionarily perfect machine.** So the idea is if they grew up on a planet that had no humans and no light then they don’t need eyes, they can only hunt by sound. **They also develop a way to protect themselves from everything else so that’s why they’re bulletproof and all these things.** I had to make it make sense. I needed the rules of the monster to adhere as tightly to the rules of the family. The family, we had set up all these incredible rules, and I needed the monster to not just be convenient.
>
> **And the other idea was [the armor is] also the reason why they were able to survive kind of the explosion of their planet and then survive on these meteorites, because they’ve evolved to be bulletproof.** Until they open themselves up to be vulnerable, they’re completely invulnerable.

Comment: Kinda makes me wonder what caused them to need to evolve bulletproof/planet-sized-explosion-proof armor...

Comment: @BrootsWaymb and how they survived what must have been an immensely long interstellar trip with zero preparation - no air, no food sources etc etc etc

We are talking potentially millennia here in space, crossing the void between systems.

Comment: Obviously there would be no humans on their original world, but I guess they mean similar bipeds? How did they evolve to be bulletproof? He says the monsters can't just be convenient but it sure sounds like they are.

Comment: I don't think the development of their armor was that far-fetched.  Like humans, they probably had conflicts with others of their kind, hence the armor.  Human hegemony is unchallenged by any other animal on Earth, yet that didn't stop us from developing bullet-proof vests.